# Select element event on drop arrow

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a select element that I need to populate with options when you click on the arrow. Looking for a solution using vanilaJS.
I can do it with the 'click' event, but it has the drawback of also firing when I select an option. I may be able to get around this issue but was wandering if there is another way.
Thank you.
Best Regards
          Luis

Comment: Why do you want the list to be empty until a user tries to select something?

Comment: Simply use the `click'`, but always check if there is children/`option`'s before populating the `select`

Comment: @LaurensMäkel Which items to populate it with might depend on another elements selection

Comment: I'm selecting from a list of available serial ports, and that may change so only when I am ready to select/change the com port i want to use, would I need to know which ones are available.

Comment: LGSon That may work for hte first time but after that you will have some options on it. I may be able to do something about that, but was looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: At this stage the Serial port Settings/connect panel is part of the page, I may just hide it and populate the list when the serial port panel is accessed.

Comment: Why not set the options when the depending options are getting set?